# clear all change when delete value in input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem in Javascript
It is when you delete the value of the field or change it
the jquery effects still exist
Is there a way to clear all the changes when i delete the value from input

this is example
http://enjaz.tech/xlab/progress/
try type 6 in then type 2

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           var pram = $('#getId').val()
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'call.php?q='+pram,
                success: function(data){

                    for(var i = 0 ; i < data ; i++){
                        var $steps = $('.amg-step');
                        if (i > 0) { $($steps[i - 1]).removeClass('--previous'); }
                        $($steps[i]).removeClass('--active').addClass('--complete').addClass('--previous');
                        if (i < $steps.length) { $($steps[i + 1]).addClass('--active'); }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset all previously added classes:

```
var $steps = $('.amg-step').removeClass('--previous').removeClass('--complete').removeClass('--active');
```

Or a shortened version of the ajax `success` function:

```
var $steps = $('.amg-step').removeClass('--previous --complete --active');
for(var i = 0 ; i < data ; i++){
    if (i > 0) { 
        $($steps[i - 1]).removeClass('--previous'); 
    }
    $($steps[i]).removeClass('--active').addClass('--complete').addClass('--previous');
    if (i < $steps.length) { $($steps[i + 1]).addClass('--active'); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your input is empty, You need to clear out all the classes and then make only the first one active. Use below code

```
$('.amg-step').removeClass('--previous --complete --active'); //to clear all

$('.amg-step:eq(0)').addClass('--active'); // make first one active
```

Place this code just above your ajax call

Comment: when i add this code .. i need it when i delete value from input

Comment: add it after your `var pram = $('#getId').val()` line.

Comment: @haitham if mine or Alon Eitan's answer resolved your issue then I would suggest you to mark either of them as answer, If the answer was only the first line of code then mark Alon Eitan's answer as he suggested it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set brand new class attribute

```
$('.amg-step').attr('class', 'amg-step');
```

Comment: This might not work properly when the elements may have additional classes other than all the `--`  prefixed classes - It will remove those classes as well leaving only `amg-step` (But it's ok for this specific scenario)